# Java Persistence (JPA) heap Issue

Tags: java, jpa, memory-leaks, glassfish

I have a simple EAR application running on Glassfish using JPA. It reads records from my Oracle DB table and processes them. Once processed they are marked as so in the database and I then call clear() on the entity manager so the processed objects can be detached and GC'ed. However, even though since we added the clear() heap usages decreased the overall heap is still increasing and eventually hits the max heap. There are no other objects which can be causing the leak and I have no idea what more I can do. We also have the JPA cache off.

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

Does anyone know what more I can do to make sure there are no JPA objects being kept? Could it be anything to do with transactions? We use a new transaction each time we update the last batch of records to processed.

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. I know I can profile the application but it is quite hard to see the issue and even if I do I expect it to be some JPA objects which are not being collected and I am not sure what I am missing in terms of clearing up entities once they are no longer required.

James

Answer (score 2):

Using a memory profiler such as JProfiler is your best solution.

Otherwise try to narrow down where the memory leak occurs.  Try removing each part of your processing until you find the culprit.

Do you run out of memory over time, or are you processing one big transaction that eventually runs out of memory?

Ensure that you have nothing holding onto the objects that you are processing.  Perhaps include some of your code.  Do you do any complex queries?